# How to set up the RDP connection to connect one computer to another computer in the Home network?

Tags: windows-10, lan, home-networking, remote

How to set up the RDP connection to connect one computer to another computer in the Home network?

Both the computers are running on Windows 10. I am trying to connect the Desktop from my Laptop.

I have enabled the Remote Connection feature in the Desktop (Portable Mini Desktop).

I have wired the Laptop and the Desktop using the Ethernet Cable.

I have enabled the Remote Access, Turned off the Windows Firewall.

When i ran the ping Desktop-HOSTNAME from my laptop, I am getting response.

When i gave the username / password, authentication is not going through. Facing error as " Your credentials did not work "

Comment: Connect them both to the same router, so they get easily-routable IP addresses, rather than to each other, where they'll get 169.254 addresses

Comment: At this moment, I have router. But, I am in the process of travelling. I wonder, whether i can have my portable desktop and access through my laptop.

Comment: Do we have any third party software's available to suffice this purpose?

Comment: You don't need any. Config both machines with static IPs on the same subnet & do it that way.

Comment: To be clear. Step # 1 : Set up the Static IP. Step # 2 : I still required to have the Ethernet cable to connect the computers.  -> Please correct me, if i am wrong. I presume, Static IP will remain, even if i traveled around.

Comment: it can be that you have to enable the ports in the windows firewall. To test, disable the firewall and see if you can connect now. Then enable the firewall and see if you can find the setting to pass through Remote Desktop

Comment: I turned off the Windows Firewall. I did't do anything on Static IP. Because, I want to carry my portable desktop  along with laptop. Because my desktop carries so much content, I will have to use my desktop through RDP from Laptop

Comment: I have turned off the firewall. Enabled Remote Access. At this moment, I am facing " Your credentials did not work ".  --  I didn't do any on the IP part.

Comment: This is completed. I am able to do.  Thank you every one.

Comment: No need of Static IP. Extremely simple to do so ..!! Thanks !!